# Threading and sleep()

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-usage

For a game I'm working on, I wanted to throw the audio on another thread so I could queue up sounds and have them immediately play.  The code I'm using in that thread looks like this

```
private void _checkForThingsToPlay()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_song != null)
        {
            _playSong(_song);
            _song = null;
        }

        while (_effects.Count > 0)
            _playSfx(_effects.Dequeue());

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

This runs asynchronously and works beautifully.  However, without the call to sleep it eats up an entire core on the cpu.  My questiom is, is sleep() an efficient way to lower the CPU usage or are there better ways to do this?  My friend and I feel like this is a quick hack.

Comment: If you can use the Reactive Framework (Rx) then you'll find a whole bunch of "Schedulers" for sequencing asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) and can be easily solved. If you are using .NET 4, try `BlockingCollection`. There's a good sample code in the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Note this line in the sample code:

```
while (true) Console.WriteLine(bc.Take());
```

That will actually block (no CPU cycles wasted) until there is something to *consume*.

Comment: I swapped all my queues out for BlockingCollections and set my loop up similar to yours (I just changed my dequeue() to take()).  However, I'm still getting high CPU usage, so I assume it's not blocking.  Is there more to this besides calling Take()?

Comment: Nevermind, something else is eating up the CPU.  Audio thread is blocking fine now.

Answer (score 7):

It is usually a bad habit to use `Thread.Sleep()` inside a `while(true)` loop. It looks like you have a queue on which you want to push sound effects and you want the "audio thread" to play these effects as soon as they are pushed on the queue. This sounds like a [producer/consumer queue](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_WaitHandle_Producer_Consumer_Queue). There are multiple ways to build such a queue in C#. You could use `Monitor.Wait()` and `Monitor.Pulse()` or you could use an `AutoResetEvent` object.

In .NET 4 you could also use a `BlockingCollection`.

By the way, there is a very good online introduction into [threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) that describes a lot of common threading/synchronization scenarios and best practices.